# How to calculate the Dusk Giant's stats?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters

I am trying to make the stat-block of a Dusk Giant (Heroes of Horror p. 147) which has advanced to 24 HD. However, trying to add up all the Cannibalize bonuses, it doesn't seem to add up with the existing stat-blocks. The Strength seems too high according to my calculations, just like its Constitution and Natural Armour.

What am I missing? How do I correctly calculate its advancement?

Comment: It might be helpful to include what you've got so far in terms of stats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The dusk giant's printed statistics are accurate

The dusk giant (*Heroes of Horror* 147-9) advances using the extraordinary ability cannibalize according to the following chart:

```
  HD   NA   STR  CON   NOTES
 6d8   +6    20   18   Medium
 7d8   +6    21   18
 8d8   +7    22   19
 9d8   +7    23   19
10d8   +8    24   20
11d8   +8    25   20
12d8   +9    26   21   Large (+8 Str, −2 Dex, +4 Con, +2 natural armor)*
13d8   +9    27   21
14d8  +10    28   22
15d8  +10    29   22
16d8  +11    30   23
17d8  +11    31   23
18d8  +12    32   24   Huge (+8 Str, −2 Dex, +4 Con, +3 natural armor)*
19d8  +12    33   24
20d8  +13    34   25
21d8  +13    35   25
22d8  +14    36   26
23d8  +14    37   26
24d8  +15    38   27

                       * Parenthetical bonuses and penalties listed
                         above from size increases are cumulative.
```

In both the lesser and greater dusk giant's cases, the printed stats match these stats I compiled by hand. Just remember, he's gotta keep on eating sentient creatures to keep these improved Hit Dice.

Comment: Those bonuses listed at the NOTES is what I'm missing. Where do those come from? It's not part of the HD advancement/Size increment table in MM.

Comment: Nevermind, found the right section. Improving Monsters... *Starts rubbing her hands together*

Comment: Search down for [Size Increases](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/improvingMonsters.htm). That's what's referenced in the description of the cannibalize ability.